# Override BackKeyPress in a classlibrary, is that possible on WP8?

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-phone-8, popup, class-library

I pass a PhoneApplicationPage instance to a classlibrary, and popup an usercontrol in this classlibrary, when I press back button, the whole application exit. Yesterday I sovled the problem in an application, but I cannot use the method in this classlibrary case.
I tried to subscribe to the event(BackKeyPress), but VS2012 says "parent_BackKeyPress" "System.EventHandler" override and delegate cannot match. I checked, they match.

PhoneApplicationPage mContext=...;
mContext.BackKeyPress += new EventHandler(parent_BackKeyPress);
void parent_BackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            ppChangePIN.IsOpen = false;
            Application.Current.RootVisual.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

anything incorrect here? plus, can I use navigationservice in classlibrary?  I did this before to navigate to a page created in the classlibrary like below, well it ends up crashing. Some say can't use pages in classlibrary, instead we should use Popup(usercontrol).
 mContext.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ChangePINPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: as per my knowledge you can not override backkeypress in class library and you can not use navigation service in class library

Comment: i did not get why you want override backkeyperss? describe here  what actually you want to do..so i can help you

Comment: Ok, so glad to have you help me! Here it is: my company has this task to compile a dll for a client. This dll will be referenced by our client's application to show several pages(which u said impossible, so I use popup usercontrol instead). But now when I press back button, my client's application exit, which is not allowed. u got me?

Comment: NO NOT exactly but if you don't want to close application on back button than write e.cancel=true in backkeypress event.

Comment: give me some brief description about your application.as off now i understand you have one clicnt ready application and in this app you add one dll and user control.and on back key press you close user control and than close application

Comment: the problem is i cannot override backkeypress event in a dll. my client's app ia A, my dll is D. A has a page with a button on it, when i click this button, A will call D's function F, F will popup an usercontrol U. now when i press back button, i want U disappear and the app goes back to A. but actually when i press back button, the app exits directly instead of goes back to A.

Comment: :okey than you are not using this method?....              protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(PopupOpen== True)
        { 
          ppChangePIN.IsOpen=false;

         PopupOpen=False;
         e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {}
    }

Comment: if this method is exicute than i dont think your app is exit

Comment: plase debug on backkeypress event of A...and put condition like if(A==open){ than e.cancel=true; usercondrol.visibility=visibility.collaps}else{}

Comment: it's not allowed to override [protected override void OnBackKeyPress] in a class. I mean no page, just a .cs file with several function. Anyway, I did it with the method lisp wrote bellow. I'm not sure if I get this right, we should Get currentPage first, then handle the backkeypress event. :)

Comment: okey fine AND best luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully done just that:

```
// or some other method of accessing the current page
// - but via Application, to which you have access also in class library
var currentPage = (PhoneApplicationPage)((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;
currentPage.BackKeyPress += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // Display dialog or something, and when you decide not to perform back navigation:
        args.Cancel = true;
    };
```

Of course you have to make sure that this code is executed if and only if the CurrentPage is the main page.

I also use Pages in class library. You *can* use NavigationService in class library: you can get it for example from current page obtained as above (`currentPage.NavigationService`). Or you could use the Navigate method of PhoneApplicationFrame:

```
((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual)
    .Navigate(
        new Uri(
            "/ClassLibraryName;component/SamplePage.xaml", 
            UriKind.Relative));
```

As the short Uris like "/SamplePage.xaml" will work in Application Project, to navigate to page in class library you have to give full location: "/ClassLibraryName;component/SamplePage.xaml".

But note, that if the application chooses to display message box to *stop from exiting*, it will not pass certification, as (from [Technical certification requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)):

> 5.2.4.2 – Back button: first screen
>
> Pressing the Back button from the first screen of an app must close the app.

Comment: hi dude, I think i already tried the method u wrote above, it ends up with a crash(debugger navigation failed), but i will try it again tomorrow. many say that we cannot use page in dlls, r u sure u ever used it in dll successfully?

Comment: @Enniswen Yes, it's actually pretty straightforward. You just have to use full location, like: `Navigate(new Url("/ClassLibraryName;component/Pages/SamplePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative))`.

Comment: Thanks dude, the back button thing works normal now, but navigation in dll still cannot work, it fails here:private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Comment: @Enniswen First: what is the content (Exeption and Uri) of NavigationFailedEventArgs? Perhaps post it in the question.

Comment: Exception: TargetInvocationException. {System.InvalidOperationException: No XAML was found at the location '/ChangePINPage.xaml'.
   at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.EndLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: @Enniswen Perhaps you missed one of my earlier comments, so I edited my answer - your Uri is wrong, it should be "ClassLibraryName;component/ChangePINPage.xaml", where ClassLibraryName stand for the name of your class library ;)

Comment: Itried ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(new Uri("/CCBbank_DM;component/ChangePINPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); and no exception this time but it navigates to a Black Page whith nothing on it. why is this?

Comment: @Enniswen Because ChangePINPage.xaml has nothing on it? Maybe everything is Collapsed, maybe there's something wrong with your styles, the bigger your app is, the more possible reasons there are. But now you are able to build a minimal example that proves possibility of navigation in class library.

Comment: Yes, you r right, my mainpage is collapsed, that's why it shows nothing. Now it workes perfectly! Thank you very much! :P

Comment: I am now have another similar problem, using xaml or image in classlibrary on Win8 store apps. is it possible?

Comment: @Enniswen I have no experience in W8 apps, so I can't help you there